# Redirect to trailng slash (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Trying to add trailing slash to every link. i.e. http://mysite.com/products should make 301 redirect to http://mysite.com/products/ etc. But how? Here is htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.css$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pack$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /modules/system/css_compactor.php?filename=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.js$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pack$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /modules/system/js_compactor.php?filename=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
RewriteRule /admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php
```

Need help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I'm using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

### CHECK FOR TRAILING SLASH - Will ignore files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Basically, this makes sure that it doesn't add a trailing to file and only folders or paths.

**EDIT**

To make it domain independent

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Replace that last line
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301] 

with

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]