# URL Redirection from .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I want to redirect www.example.com/blog to www.example.com/blog/ from htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^public\/blog$ "https\:\/\/example\.co\/blog\/" [R=301,L]
```

How to do this.

Thanx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to trailng slash (htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267755/redirect-to-trailng-slash-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

To use .htaccess :

```
Redirect [URL source] [URL dest]
```

So :

```
Redirect www.example.com/blog  www.example.com/blog/
```

Should works pretty good

Generally, people wants to delete the final "/" and not to add it. Are you tryng to do that on all your pages, or only a specific case ?

Otherwise try something like :

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: I want to use this for a specific page. I use Redirect www.example.com/blog  www.example.com/blog/ and get 500

Comment: That should works, did you activated rewrite engine extension ? And verify your TLD too